# scrambling letters php

Tags: php

i would like to scramble all a-zA-Z
so a world
like

hello
becomes
shrxs
or
bhidf

the rest should stay the same.
eg.  "hello world!"="ksgii fishl!"

etc.

Comment: The important thing to consider is what you want to scramble the text into, and what you want to be able to do with it afterwards. E.g., does it need to be possible to unscramble it? Or should it just become random, undecipherable text?

Comment: can you be more concret, do you want to scramble systematically or totally random?

Answer (score 12):

It's not clear whether this is intended to be reversible, so here are two alternative answers.

"hello" becoming "shrxs" implies a scheme that goes beyond simple subsitution (a [caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)) and perhaps something like a polyalphabetic cipher.

But for a simple caesar cipher you can use [strtr](http://php.net/strtr)

```
$plain="hello";
$cipher = strtr($plain, 
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 
    "tuvhijkcwxyzldefgsmnopqrab");
echo $cipher;
```

Would display "cizze";

If you don't need to reverse the scrambling, and want something truly random, try this

```
function random_char($matches)
{
   return chr(rand(ord('a'),ord('z')));
}

$plain="hello";

$random=preg_replace_callback(
           "{[a-z]}i",
           "random_char",
           $plain);

echo $random;
```

Here we use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to have each char replaced with a random alternative by the random_char callback.

Comment: +1 strstr can do any simple substitution cipher (for what it's worth which isn't a lot)

Answer (score 5):

You might also like to look at the [str_rot13](http://www.php.net/str_rot13) function, which has the advantage of being reversible too.

```
<?php
  var $foo = "hello world!";
  var $bar = str_rot13($foo); // $bar equals "uryyb jbeyq!"
  var $baz = str_rot13($bar); // $baz equals "hello world!"
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by scramble? I can see you're not rearranging or counting letters through the alphabet.

It sounds like you just wanted to know how to replace only a-zA-Z characters. So whatever your transformation function might be, this is one way you could do it:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/[a-zA-Z]/', 'charTransform', $oldstring);
```

Then define the transform as a callback:

```
function charTransform($matches) {
   $oldchar = $matches[0];
   return strtolower($oldchar); // replace with whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is, would you like the text scrambled or encrypted, i.e. should the text be decryptable or not? If you just want all letters replaced by some other random letter you might try something like this:

```
$text = "Hello world!\n";
$text = preg_replace_callback(
        '/[a-zA-Z]/',
        create_function('$matches', 'return chr(rand(97,122));'),
        $text
    );
```